# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() INSERT

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to use this code to check if the system already exists a field with this value

```
Dim adap As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE code ='"+ TxtCode.Text +"'"
                Dim comand As New MySqlCommand()
                comand.Connection = con
                comand.CommandText = sqlquery
                adap.SelectCommand = comand
                Dim data As MySqlDataReader
                data = comando2.ExecuteReader()
                leitor.Read()
                If (data(3).ToString) = code Then
                    MsgBox("already exists", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
                    TxtCode.ResetText()
                    TxtCode.Focus()
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine(insert("INSERT INTO client (name, tel, code) VALUES ('" & name & "', '" & tel & "')"))
                    con.Close()
                End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `leitor.Read()` but you did not call `data.Read()` in your code

Also, since your query is `SELECT * FROM client WHERE code = '1234'`, there is no need to check for `data(3) == code`. If records exist, data.Read() would be true

```
If data.Read() Then
   MsgBox("already exists", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
   TxtCode.ResetText()
   TxtCode.Focus()
Else
   Console.WriteLine(insert("INSERT INTO client (name, tel, code) VALUES ('" & name & "', '" & tel & "')"))
   con.Close()
End If
```

It is also a good practice to use Parameters instead of concatenation

```
  Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE code = @code"
  ...

  command.Parameters("@code", code); //this is safer
```

and for your insert

```
 "INSERT INTO client (name, tel, code) VALUES (@name, @tel)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting two values but specifying 3 values for the input

This line

```
"INSERT INTO client (name, tel, code) VALUES ('" & name & "', '" & tel & "')"
```

should be something like

```
"INSERT INTO client (name, tel, code) VALUES ('" & name & "', '" & tel & "','" & code & "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
 public bool isPhoneInfo(string hashPhone)
    {
        using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(_connStrng))
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "CALL SP_IS_PHONEINFO(?p_hashInfo);";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?p_hashInfo", hashPhone);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string hashPhoneInfo = dr["hashPhone"].ToString();
                    if (!hashPhoneInfo.Equals(string.Empty))
                        return true;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error in : "+e);
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```